# SQL Select with multiple IDs

Tags: sql

I have an Address History table with three fields: `EmpID`, `Address`, `AddrID`.

Every time I add a new address, I also increment the Address ID (`AddrID`) by 1 for that particular employee.

```
EmpID | AddrID | Address
-------------------------------
 1    |     1  | 1234 First Ave
 1    |     2  | 2145 First Ave
 1    |     3  | 1111 First Ave

 2    |     1  | 1001 Second St
 2    |     2  | 1002 Second St
 2    |     3  | 1003 Second St
 2    |     4  | 2222 Second St

 3    |     1  | 3332 Third Lane
 3    |     2  | 3333 Third Lane

 4    |     1  | 4444 Fourth Way
```

How do I get the most recent address (highest Address ID) for each employee?  Ideally, I should be able to return:

```
EmpID | AddrID | Address
-------------------------------
 1    |     3  | 1111 First Ave
 2    |     4  | 2222 Second St
 3    |     2  | 3333 Third Lane
 4    |     1  | 4444 Fourth Way
```

So far I have either returned too many results (ie, every Employee, every AddrID 1, and every Address associated with the two), or too few results (ie, every Employee with an AddrID 4 - just Employee 2).

I have tried using `Distinct`, `Group By`, `Order By`, `Having`, and Self-Joins to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: I did not realize I could only accept one answer.  They are both correct.

NJK's answer is succinct.
BlueFeet's answer is explicit.

Comment: Also, voting down a perfectly good question is simply spiteful.  I asked the question clearly and concisely with great examples and walkthrough for others to follow.  Please remove your -1.

Comment: +1 for having a shoe on your head.

Comment: How do you know who down-voted? Please don't accuse people of crap unless you have evidence.

Comment: While I do not have substantive proof, I did watch it happen within moments of his comment as I was browsing my history for responses to another pending question.  I find that highly circumstantial.  Point taken, Aaron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery that gets the `MAX()` addrid for each empid:

```
select t1.empid,
  t1.addrid,
  t1.address
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select max(addrid) addrid, empid
  from table1
  group by empid
) t2
  on t1.empid = t2.empid
  and t1.addrid = t2.addrid
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be2e1/1)

The inner query will return the max `addrid` and the `empid` then you join your table to that result on those two values this will limit the records that get returned.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT empid, 
               Max(addrid) AS AddrID 
        FROM   t1 
        GROUP  BY empid) a 
       JOIN t1 b 
         ON b.empid = a.empid 
            AND b.addrid = a.addrid
```

See it in [action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b864/1)

Comment: njk - quick SQL Fiddle tip: you can copy and paste OP's sample data into the "Text to DDL" tool to quickly generate the scripts needed to work with it.  For example, in this case it would produce this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d725/1  As you can imagine, doing this makes answering questions with SQL Fiddle much less tedious.  Cheers!

Comment: @JakeFeasel Cheers for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably organize the table differently, but you could do something with a sub-join

```
    select * from address_history 
    join 
    (select EmpID, max(AddrID) max_address from Address_History group by empId) as latest_addresses 
       on address_history.empid = latest_addresses 
       and address_history.addrId = latest_addresses.max_address
```